# Why is the code printing the last std::cout?

Tags: c++, vector

```
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
int f(vector<T> &v){
    return v.size();
}

template<typename T>
class B{
public:
    int size(){
        return v.size();
    };
private:
    vector<T> v;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    B<string> b;

    vector<string> v;

    for(int i=0; i<f<string>(v)-1; i++)
        std::cout << "using fn template" << endl;

    for(int i=0; i<b.size()-1; i++)
        std::cout << "using class B" << endl;

    for(int i=0; i<v.size()-1; i++)
        std::cout << "done" << endl; //Why is this printing???
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: `return (EXIT_SUCCESS);` is useless in C++. Removing 1 to vector sizes is certainly an error. Switching on warning when compiling may be a good idea.

Comment: Why is `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` useless in C++?

Comment: @Greg Not necessarily useless, but I believe we can omit the return EXIT_SUCCESS; line. The standard defines this to be well-formed when we omit the return, so it most likely returns EXIT_SUCCESS to the OS when we do so.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`vector`'s `size()` function returns a value of type `size_t` which is unsigned. So, if `size()` returns 0 and you subtract 1 from it, you're going to get a very large number rather than -1. That very large number will be greater than 0 and the condition `i < v.size() - 1` will therefore be be true since `i` is 0.

**EDIT**:

I should probably add that normally when iterating over an array or a `vector`, you iterate as long as your index is less than the size of the array or `vector` rather than size - 1.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << "done" << endl;
```

would likely be what you really want to do. Even if you used `(int)v.size() - 1` to get rid of the signed vs unsigned issue, the loop would stil be wrong because you'd miss the last element in cases where you actually had elements in the `vector`.

Comment: +1 for correct.  (The -1 on your size() is weird, you've got that already via the the use of < instead of <=.)

Comment: Modern compilers should warn about this, e.g. g++ with `-Wall` prints “warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions.” @mawandm: When compiling, enable as many warnings as possible and reasonable. For example, I usually run g++ with `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wunused`.

Comment: All I need is the first n-1 elements but use the n(th) element within the loop using v.at(i+1). That is why I need to loop to v.size() - 1